# Any better way to get first n bytes, and the rest of a String? Currently using binary_part and String.trim_leading

Tags: elixir

Given a string `str = "üabc123"`, and `size = 5`. I want to get the first 5 bytes(`"üabc"`), and the rest of the string(`"123"`).

Currently I'm doing:

```
str = "üabc123"
size = 5
a = binary_part(str, 0, size)      # "üabc"
b = String.trim_leading(str, a)    # "123"
```

Seems like there would be a cleaner way to do this. Is there another way?

Comment: Why do you want to count in bytes, not characters? If your input is `üüü12` then you will get only half of the third `ü`, which is not a valid string.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip even worse, if `"ü"` s there are in composed form (`String.normalize(:ufc)`,) the result will differ. That said, it depends on how those were produced: by typing `"ü"` with German keyboard, or by typing combined diacritical.

Answer (score 9):

You can use binary pattern matching

```
<< a::binary-size(5), b::binary >> = "üabc123"
a == "üabc"
b == "123"
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I was trying `<<a :: 40, b :: binary>>` but getting a number for `a`, didn't know about `binary-size`. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not seem to be correct; if I copy-paste it into my `iex` it produces the result you have shown, while this is a combined u-umlaut, [codepoint 252](https://unicode-table.com/en/00FC/)—try (`to_charlist("üabc123")`)—and it is indeed 1 byte only. Looks like Elixir and/or Erlang does somewhat nasty with binaries here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin that is the codepoint, not the bytes. Try `:binary.bin_to_list(<<252::utf8>>)`. I'm guessing the OP is dealing with some sort of datasource that specifies an offset in byes for a given string. At least I hope that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneline split, just out of curiosity:

```rb
# make sure u-umlaut is combined diacritical
[lead, trail] =
  str
  |> to_charlist() 
  |> Enum.split(size)
  |> Tuple.to_list()
  |> Enum.map(&to_string/1)
#⇒ ["üabc", "123"]
```